# View is not based on scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I defined a scope in my `Product` model that is:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :send_to_data # this is a boolean column
  scope :my_products, where(:send_to_data => true)
end
```

Then in my controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @my_products = current_user.products
  end
end
```

Finally my View:

```
<% for product in @my_products %>
   <%= product.user_id %>
   <%= product.name %>
   <%= product.send_to_data %>
<% end %>
```

But it still renders ALL Products including the ones flagged as false for `:send_to_data`.

How do I get the ones for my scope only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The named scope has to be used directly on products like so:

```
def index
  @my_products = current_user.products.my_products
end
```

A named scope doesn't change the default behavior of the 'products' relation. It has to be called by its name when you want to use it.

Comment: I would also rename it to something more descriptive like 'send_data' rather than 'my_products'. As it is, current_user.products.my_products sounds redundant. 'current_user.products.send_data' gives a better sense of what records you're trying to get.